# Resetting increment values in JavaScript / jQuery that are not in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do you reset incremented values in JavaScript that is not in a form?

I'm trying to create something that is similar to a decision tree, but to keep track of the clicks and then present them with the best answer, based on the highest click.

*Bonus

How would you display a message, based on the highest increment of clicks?

Down below is the fiddle link to the code:

HTML:

```
<button type="button" onClick="clickME()">Click me</button>
<button type="button" onClick="clickME2()">Click me</button>
<button type="button" onClick="clickME3()">Click me</button>
<button type="button" onClick="clickME4()">Click me</button>
    <p>Clicks1: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>
    <p>Clicks2: <a id="clicks2">0</a></p>
    <p>Clicks3: <a id="clicks3">0</a></p>
    <p>Clicks4: <a id="clicks4">0</a></p>
    <p>Most click is: <a id="clicks5"></a></p>
<button type="reset">Click me</button>
```

JS:

```
 var clicks = 0;
 var clicks2 = 0;
 var clicks3 = 0;
 var clicks4 = 0;
    function clickME() {
        clicks += 1;
        clicks2 += 1;
        clicks3 += 1;
        clicks4 += 1;
        document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
        document.getElementById("clicks2").innerHTML = clicks2;
        document.getElementById("clicks3").innerHTML = clicks3;
        document.getElementById("clicks4").innerHTML = clicks4;
 }
    function clickME2() {
        clicks += 1;
        clicks2 += 1;
        document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
        document.getElementById("clicks2").innerHTML = clicks2;
 }
    function clickME3() {
        clicks += 1;
        clicks2 += 1;
        clicks3 += 1;
        document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
        document.getElementById("clicks2").innerHTML = clicks2;
        document.getElementById("clicks3").innerHTML = clicks3
 }
    function clickME4() {
        clicks += 1;
        document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z66WF/68/

Comment: I understand your code, but I don't understand your question

Comment: If you click on a button, it increments the value, but how do you reset it to 0?

Comment: maybe just "clicks = 0;" ?

Comment: Thanks that works! and is it possible if you can answer my bonus question? Make sure to answer it in the answer part and I can declare this is solve.

Comment: alert(Math.max(clicks, clicks2, clicks3, clicks4));

Comment: Is this a classroom problem?

Comment: No this is not a classroom problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/z66WF/77/ - Answers your bonus question too

```
function reset() {
    for(var i=1; i<=4; i++) {
        document.getElementById("clicks"+i).innerHTML = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for providing this to me. Did you manage to update your jsfiddle? It look different from the last time I saw it.

Comment: Yeah. My initial answer was based on the unedited question. Then I updated it based on your question.

Comment: I updated just now too. There was one scenario I wasn't handling. Now it works perfectly. Could you please mark an answer as correct so that it helps others